# Air for IOS; share the app/score

Tags: ios, flash, air, adobe, share

is there a way to open up iOS apps to share the score of my AIR app for iOS?

I'm using Flash Pro CC with AIR SDK 16 for iOS.

I guess it is UIActivityViewController, but I am not sure if AIR supports this.

this is what I mean
https://forums.adobe.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/2-7551687-764346/600-900/IMG_2696.PNG

thank you.

Comment: The screenshot shows a `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: yes, you can open other apps from within your app to share the scores or similar stuff - is that what you are asking?

Comment: @luk2302 yes, this is what i want. I want to put a share icon in my Air app to share the score on other apps (just like the one in the screenshot). but I don't know how I could. I guess air does not have support of UIActivityViewController by default?

Comment: I have no experience with that, but you should rephrase your question to make clearer that you are trying to share custom data between apps - that way the people who know how to help you will get a chance to.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use a Native Extension to do it. There are some that you could try (free and paid). I do recommend you, to download the Adobe Gaming SDK (available in your Creative Cloud account), after downloading you will find a folder called "Native Extensions (ANEs)", and a file called Social.ane.
You also have a Samples folder listing all steps to be able to use the respective and other ANEs (source code included).

Comment: thank you, yes I already am trying Adobe Gaming SDK, it goes well, I am getting used to. I guess I got the idea how Game Center works with AIR, but I keep getting this error when I try to publish the App with Adobe Gaming SDK.. Any idea ? "Error: libgameCenter.a are required to have universal iOS libraries. Please contact the ANE developer(s) to get the same."

Comment: Check if you are using the latest AIR SDK (16 or 17) and that you are using a version of this ANE that has 64 bits support.

Comment: it is AIR latest (17.0.0.172) , and I downloaded GAMING SDK here https://creative.adobe.com/products/gaming-sdk .. is it not supported to have 64 bits support?